# Как применить цветовой фильтр к изображению через css?

Tags: html, изображения, css

Необходимо изображение отобразить в явно заданном цветовом спектре.
В моем случае иконка полностью черная, а хотелось бы, скажем, получить красную или оранжевую.
Яндекс преимущественно выдавал -webkit-filter, но я так и не понял как его применить в данном случае.
Спасибо!

Comment: Спасибо за ответ soledar10! но появился еще вопрос: как победить изображение, которое имеет только оттенки серого?

Comment: Решение не найдено. Есть возможность изменить цвет за счет других цветов на изображении, но если рисунок монохромный -- не выходит.

Comment: Всем участникам спасибо!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если кому нужно кроссбраузерное решение, то вот [код](http://jsfiddle.net/r8W9G/7/):

```css
.fimg {
  position: relative;
  /* Нужно, чтобы абсолютно позиционированные дочерние элементы позиционировались относительно края родителя. */
  display: inline-block;
}
.fimg img,
.filter {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
.filter {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  /* Принудительно размещаем фильтр прямо над изображением. */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Фильтр расположен на один уровень выше изображения. */
  position: absolute;
  /* Абсолютно позиционированный элемент. Поскольку позиционирование родителя задано как relative, позиция фильтра задаётся относительно края родителя. */
  background-color: rgba(254, 128, 128, .29);
  /* Первые три числа -- десятичное значение цвета в RGB, четвёртое -- прозрачность, в сотых, от 0 (полностью прозрачен) до 1 (полностью непрозрачен). Запись .29 аналогична 0.29. */
}
```

```html
<div class="fimg">
  <!-- Оборачиваем фильтр и картинку в div, чтобы у них был общий родитель. -->
  <span class="filter"></span> 
  <!-- Фильтр -->
  <img src="http://bezproblem.ucoz.ru/iconki/cerno_belye/1/02.png" alt="" />
  <!-- Изображение -->
</div>
```

Comment: Но ведь png с прозрачностью превратится в прямогульник заданного цвета. Конечно за неимением лучшего может пригодится, но совсем не то.

Answer (score 4):

http://jsfiddle.net/R2WPG/

http://jsfiddle.net/aSFeR/

- изменяя значение hue-rotate(100deg); - получаете нужный цвет от 0 до 360

Спецификация

https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/FXTF/raw-file/tip/filters/index.html#FilterFunction

Поддержка браузерами

http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/R2WPG/1/
похожий случай у меня. суть я понял. здесь речь идет о рисунках, которые имеют хоть бы еще один оттенок, кроме серого.

Comment: Вообще не кроссбраузерно. В IE и Firefox работать не будет. Смысл?

Comment: Все же на месте не стоит - в будущем может будет и работать

Comment: Если у вас есть решение, тем более кроссбраузерное, то я буду только рад!

Comment: Для кроссбраузерного решения используйте иконки необходимого цвета - как вариант

Comment: @Azat Khanov, ловите)