# Изменить цвет изображения в css

Tags: html, css, css3, вёрстка

Как можно (если вообще возможно) изменить цвет картинки с помощью css? К примеру есть иконка черного цвета, ее нужно сделать скажем красного цвета. Это возможно вообще?

Comment: А можете, пожалуйста, картинку добавить, чтобы не показывать на какой-то левой (хотя и так тоже можно)?

Comment: С большой вероятностью вам подойдут ответы отсюда: [Как применить цветовой фильтр к изображению через css?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/297703/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%86%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d1%80-%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-css). Если нет, отредактируйте вопрос, добавьте подробностей, почему не подходят (например, если нужно допотопные браузеры поддерживать и т.п.)

Answer (score 3):

Допустим есть картинка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/output/food-q-g-200-200-5.jpg");
  background-color: red;
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

Свойство `background-blend-mode` имеет очень много опций, почти на любой вкус и цвет. https://css-tricks.com/basics-css-blend-modes/

Единственный минус — это полное отсутствие IE и Microsoft Edge.
http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-backgroundblendmode

Comment: Да натыкался на него когда гуглил этот вопрос, но оно к сожалению мне не подходит.

Comment: А можете уточнить почему?

Comment: @ConstantineShibaev лучше сразу это уточнение добавьте в вопрос, чтобы остальные отвечающие сразу видели.

Answer (score 1):

Обычно для того чтобы стилизовать иконки используют [Шрифтовые иконки](http://fontawesome.io)
или [SVG](http://css.yoksel.ru/svg-decoration/), если иконка незаменима тогда любой svg редактор к примеру [inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/download/) может векторизовать (преобразовать в svg) вашу иконку, и уже в svg можно залить ее к себе на сайт. Вот [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ESXJ_0Fa0rs) где можно наглядно посмотреть как это сделать.

Comment: Значит стандартными средствами css/css3 никак нельзя изменить исходный цвет растровой картинки?

Comment: @ConstantineShibaev, только если фильтрами как-то

Comment: К растру можно только применить фильтры. https://habrahabr.ru/post/144852/ , подробнее в статье с примерами, но поддержка в браузерах пока слабовата. Самый оптимальный способ переделать иконку в svg или изменить в фотошопе)

Comment: @junior-web-dev хорошо, благодарю